# Conditional replacement of values in a matrix in DolphinDB

Tags: conditional-statements, dolphindb

For example, matrix A = matrix(1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9).
How can I replace all the values smaller than 5 with a specified value? The desired output  is(5 5 5, 5 5 6, 7 8 9)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the result in three different ways in DolphinDB. See the following code：

Method 1:
Use function `iif`

```
iif(a<5, 5, a)
```

Method 2:
Use conditional expressions

```
(a<5) *5 + (a>=5) * a
```

Method 3:
Use user-defined functions

```
m=each(def(mutable x){x[x<5]=5;return x},a)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).